# Are questions asked 'n' plus years ago, still relevant?

Tags: support

I am new to Ubuntu and have been researching varies methods to accomplish certain tasks that I want done.  Some of my research has led me to questions asked in 2012. And I am hesitate in trying the answers/suggestions to those questions. I am working with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Gnome 3) for now and have installed kubuntu.desktop (Plasma).  So, are questions asked 'n' years ago, still relevant to current supported Ubuntu distro's and officially recognized derivatives?  If that is the case, are deprecated Q&A removed?

If this is a duplicate then I will remove, but I didn't see any questions concerning this topic.

Comment: There's a lot of obsolete material posted on Ask Ubuntu. I have seen many times that obsolete material with hundreds of upvotes is removed by the Stack Overflow moderators, so I know that it is possible to remove it. Stack Overflow considers itself to be an up-to-date resource for programmers, not an archive for storing old posts because they have historical interest.

Comment: Some related posts: [Old question with old answer. How can I request an update on the topic?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/2896), [What is the most appropriate way to bring an old/outdated question up to date?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/11991), [Should we go ahead and delete out-dated content?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/5615)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, are questions asked 'n' years ago, still relevant to current supported Ubuntu distro's and officially recognized derivatives?

It depends on the question. Some are, some are not. Questions related to server editions tend to still be current; so core related questions last a lot longer than an Ubuntu release. Apache and mysql related questions can also still be current. Or if not current, can lead to the answer to the current question with a slight adjustment to the result.

> If that is the case, are deprecated Q&A removed?

No those are not removed. AskUbuntu is also an archive.

Mind that there are also loads and loads of users still using older releases. Heck, we  had a 6.06 running ourself up to 2018. Those users will still depend on old questions.

Comment: What would be nice is a relevant tag be added to those that meet the archive.  Meaning if a year has passed after the question was asked the version that the question relates to will be added.  Then when the answer does not relate to the current verson a deprecated tag be added.

Comment: The definition of "irrelevant" is impossible to define for a question unless someone visually examines a question and has knowledge about the question.

Comment: The definition of "current version" is also vague there, @dmbGamer7 - 'current version' would suggest only the latest Ubuntu, when **in fact** we support all Releases of Ubuntu and its official variants through End of Life.  Once it's EOL, we still keep all previous questions asked for that version of Ubuntu, and *future* ones get closed with the EOL-specific close reason.

Comment: And even end of life is obscure nowadays... We have 6 months 3 years on some parts fir lts and 5 years for lts